# C# No information returning in console

Tags: c#, list, oop, object, methods

Sorry for what is probably a really stupid question but I'm just learning C# in class and I am having trouble with an assignment. I have these two methods in my HourlyEmployee class that is not returning any information. And I don't have an error message so I am having trouble trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Program.cs File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Assignment5
{
    abstract class Employee
    {
        private string firstName = "";
        private string lastName = "";
        private int EmployeeID;

        public Employee(string firstname, string lastname, int employeeid)
        {
            firstName = firstname;
            lastName = lastname;
            EmployeeID = employeeid;
        }

        public abstract float CalculatePay();

    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            employees.Add(new HourlyEmployee("Joe", "Smith", 1234, 12.50f, 40));
            employees.Add(new CommissionEmployee("Alice", "Mason", 4321, 20, 1000));
            employees.Add(new HourlyEmployee("Richard", "Lionheart", 1212, 11.75f, 43));
            employees.Add(new CommissionEmployee("Mark", "Wells", 9876, 21, 4300));

            foreach(Employee e in employees)
            {
                e.CalculatePay();
                e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HourlyEmployee.cs File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Assignment5
{
    class HourlyEmployee : Employee
    {
        public float hourlyRate;
        public int hoursWorked;
        public float employeePay;
        private string firstname;
        private string lastname;
        private int employeeid;

        public HourlyEmployee(string firstname, string lastname, int employeeid,
            float hourlyRate, int hoursWorked) : base(firstname, lastname, employeeid) { }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Employee: " + firstname + " " + lastname + " with ID of " + employeeid + " makes $" + hourlyRate
                             + " per hour and worked for " + hoursWorked + " hours. We owe them " + employeePay + ".");
        }

        public override float CalculatePay()
        {
            employeePay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
            return employeePay;
        }
    }
}
```

My CalculatePay() and ToString() methods are definitely busted and I am not sure what I did wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source code is probably ok. I think you want to display the message produced by `ToString()` method, so you need to tell the program to do so. I mean, method `ToString` is returning a `string` but you're doing nothing with it. Use [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.8) function for that.

Example:

```
foreach(Employee e in employees)
{
    e.CalculatePay();
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I agree. ToString() doesn't do anything except attempt to convert whatever it's attached to to a string. You need to take another step to actually display it. To go a little further, Console.WriteLine() is part of the System namespace which you happened to already have included so it's just FYI in the future.  .

Comment: @HazardousGlitch yeah. Other answers says that OP is not assigning any value to the properties, but I think he is when `HourlyEmployee`'s constructor calls `base` constructor, which is actually assigning the params values to the properties. I didn't tested it, guessing by eye.

Comment: well.. the issue presented here, that we're addressing in this question, isn't necessarily related to why the OP wants to console.output. or whether the instance here has populated values or is failing to initialize all properties\fields correct.. it is just as you said, it isn't be console logged or output.  With this answer, the OP might ask us in another question using the output as to what the problem is, but I think they will figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I got confused because I thought return worked kind of like a Console.WriteLine so I figured it would output all that information. I still have some other issues but I think I can figure it out from here now. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're just not assigning anything to `hourlyRate` and `hoursWorked`

You should assign them from the constructor parameters within the constructor.

Edit: and also as DontVoteMeDown caught - you're not actually outputting anything within `Main`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! hourlyRate and hoursWorked is actually in another file that I didn't mention. I figured once I had the answer to one I would figure it out since they were set up super similarly. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`hourlyRate` and `hoursWorked` are not initialized in your code and the default value is `0`.

you may initialize these values from the constructor of your `HourlyEmployee` class as below: -

```
 public HourlyEmployee(string firstname, string lastname, int employeeid,
            float hourlyRate, int hoursWorked) : base(firstname, lastname, employeeid)
        {
            this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
            this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        }
```

Also you you may have the following fields as private.

```
public float hourlyRate;
public int hoursWorked;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! I am also realizing that I don't seem to be inheriting the firstname, lastname, or employeeID. Haha. But that was one mystery solved!